# how do I calculate more then 2 variables in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i got an a problem when i want to do calculation my input more then 2 variable, in examples var A
= 1, var B = 2, var C = A + B, var D = 3, var E = C + D.

Here example working calculation.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {GrossSale: 0.0, SaleRet: 0.0};
}

render() {
var A = this.state.GrossSale;
var B = this.state.SaleRet;

var C = A - B;

return (
  //here my input code
);
}
```

Here example calculation that output NaN, the var K is SUM all of the variable. the output should calculate of A - J variable.

```
class Cogs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Begining: 0.0,
      Purch: 0.0,
      Freight: 0.0,
      DirectLab: 0.0,
      InvAvaible: 0.0,
      EndingInv: 0.0,
    };
  }

  render() {
    var A = this.state.Begining;
    var B = this.state.Purch;
    var C = A + B;

    var D = this.state.Freight;
    var E = C + D;

    var F = this.state.DirectLab;
    var G = E + F;

    var H = this.state.InvAvaible;
    var I = G + H;

    var J = this.state.EndingInv;
    var K = I - J;

    return (
     //here my input code
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Define: "not working"

Comment: Why have you not added `console.log` statements to your render method so you can see where the bad state variable is coming from?  You know how to use F12 debugging tools, right?

Comment: @selbie, sorry, im newbie in react-native enviroment. im using VSCode for text editor. i dont know how to use F12, is that in android studio?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this was react-native.  In any case, I would assume a console.log statement goes to the Android Studio console when debugging. Learn how to set break points.